# rails datatables TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I'm trying to run datatables in a Rails app but
it doesn't work out for me.

in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Shell command to check presence:

```
gem list | grep -i datatables

jquery-datatables-rails (1.12.2)
```

application.css:

```
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

application.js

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

clients.js

```
jQuery ->
$('#clients').dataTable()
```

Should init datatables right?

Firebug errors:

```
TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function


$('#clients').dataTable();
```

or:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


$('#clients').dataTable({
```

Any ideas? thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error message recently. First of all, do you set the id in your table tag? Do you have thead and tbody tag in your table?

```
<table id='clients'>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>...</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Second: You are using `->` symbol, that is CoffeeScript replacement of function keyword, besides  CoffeeScript is tab sensitive. Make sure that your CoffeeScript file name end with `.coffee`. I would try with tab and changing the file name.

clients.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#clients').dataTable()
```

Maybe with these changes you would end with your DataTable working.